# Where to put Request Interstitial Ad function in code?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

To keep having ads when ever i want to show them what do you think the right place to put this function in; is it Start() ? Start is called once the game object spawned so how ill keep having ads ??

```
public void RequestInterstitialAd()
{
    interstitalAd = new InterstitialAd(interstitalAdID);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    interstitalAd.LoadAd(adRequest);

    interstitalAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
    interstitalAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
    interstitalAd.OnAdOpening += HandleOnAdOpened;
    interstitalAd.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
    interstitalAd.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, do it at 'Start' method of static GameObject. because it needs to be initialized once, not several times.

Comment: it will keep loading ads even its called once ?

Comment: yeah, only once. and it should be.

Comment: thx for your answert but i found that you need to call it everytime u need to show an ad

Comment: you should call once initialization of ad but show or anything others should call proper location of codes.

Comment: i did it only in start and call DisplayInterstitialAd() function every 3rd time a scene is loaded and didnt work it like i need to loadAd() function everytime i need to show an ad

Answer (score 0):

I need to call it everytime i need to show an ad so i did this :

```
public class AdMobManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static AdMobManager instance;//to have the right to call this class functions and variables without the need to put static to each one from another class 
    [SerializeField]
    private string appID,interstitalAdID;
    private InterstitialAd interstitalAd;
    public bool isAdOpened,isAdClosed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        instance = this;
        MobileAds.Initialize(appID);
        RequestInterstitialAd();//load an ad from the first time game is opened
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }

    public void RequestInterstitialAd()
    {
        if(interstitalAd != null)//remove the old interstital ad showed before to create a new one 
        {
            interstitalAd.Destroy();
        }
        interstitalAd = new InterstitialAd(interstitalAdID);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        interstitalAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
        interstitalAd.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
        interstitalAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
        interstitalAd.OnAdOpening += HandleOnAdOpened;
        interstitalAd.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
        interstitalAd.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;
        Debug.Log("Ads Request Created");//used to test
    }

    public void DisplayInterstitialAd()
    {
        if (interstitalAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitalAd.Show();
        }
    }

    public void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLoaded event received");
    }
    public void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender,AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleFailedToReciveAd event received with message: " + args.Message);
    }
    public void HandleOnAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");
        isAdOpened = true;
    }
    public void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender,EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdClosed event received");
        isAdClosed = true;
        isAdOpened = false;//initialise
        RequestInterstitialAd();//everytime we show an ad load another one when the first one is closed
    }
    public void HandleOnAdLeavingApplication(object sender,EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLeavingApplication event recived");
    }


}
```